# Saving extracted array into new netcdf file

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray, netcdf4

I have a netcdf file which looks like this:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (time: 180, d2: 2, lat: 180, lon: 360)
Coordinates:
  * time       (time) object 2000-01-15 12:00:00 ... 2014-12-15 12:00:00
  * lat        (lat) float64 -89.5 -88.5 -87.5 -86.5 ... 86.5 87.5 88.5 89.5
  * lon        (lon) float64 0.5 1.5 2.5 3.5 4.5 ... 356.5 357.5 358.5 359.5
Dimensions without coordinates: d2
Data variables:
    time_bnds  (time, d2) object ...
    lat_bnds   (lat, d2) float64 ...
    lon_bnds   (lon, d2) float64 ...
    zos        (time, lat, lon) float32 ...
Attributes: (12/45)
    Conventions:            CF-1.7 CMIP-6.2
    activity_id:            CMIP
    case_id:                23
    cesm_casename:          b.e21.BHIST.f09_g17.CMIP6-historical.009
    contact:                cesm_cmip6@ucar.edu
    creation_date:          2019-01-27T12:33:42Z
    ...                     ...
    variable_id:            zos
    variant_info:           CMIP6 20th century experiments (1850-2014) with C...
    variant_label:          r9i1p1f1
    branch_time_in_parent:  295650.0
    branch_time_in_child:   674885.0
    branch_method:          standard
```

I extracted a spatial partition of the data while retaining all the time slices:

```
lat_bnds, lon_bnds = [25, 50], [-85 + 360, -60 + 360]
lats = DS.variables['lat'][:]
lons = DS.variables['lon'][:]
lat_inds = np.where((lats > lat_bnds[0]) & (lats < lat_bnds[1]))
lon_inds = np.where((lons > lon_bnds[0]) & (lons < lon_bnds[1]))
lat_inds_2 = list(lat_inds[0])
lon_inds_2 = list(lon_inds[0])
DS_subset = DS.variables['zos'][:, lat_inds_2, lon_inds_2]
```

This extracted data DS_subset looks like this:

```
<xarray.Variable (time: 180, lat: 25, lon: 25)>
[112500 values with dtype=float32]
Attributes: (12/19)
    cell_measures:  area: areacello
    cell_methods:   area: mean where sea time: mean
    comment:        Model data on the 1x1 grid includes values in all cells f...
    description:    This is the dynamic sea level, so should have zero global...
    frequency:      mon
    id:             zos
    ...             ...
    time_label:     time-mean
    time_title:     Temporal mean
    title:          Sea Surface Height Above Geoid
    type:           real
    units:          m
    variable_id:    zos
```

Now I am trying to save this extracted data *DS_subset* as a new netcdf file:

```
new_filename = './data/newfile.nc'
xr.Dataset(DS_subset.to_xarray()).to_netcdf(path=new_filename)
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
AttributeError: 'Variable' object has no attribute 'to_xarray'
```

Could you all please suggest what I am doing wrong? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If I have well understand, you want to select a part of your dataset and export it to a new netcdf file.

As raised, `to_xarray()` is not an existing xarray function. To convert your `DS_subset` into a dataset, `xr.Dataset()` requires a dict-like argument (https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.html). This should make your code work:

```
xr.Dataset({"your_var_name":DS_subset}).to_netcdf(path=new_filename)
```

Nevertheless, I may also suggest some improvments to your approach:

I guess you'd like to obtain a "full" netcdf file with the same characteristics (dimensions, attributes, encodings...) as your original file. In that case you don't need to specifically extract `xarray.Variables` by using `DS.variables[...]`. You can just use `DS[...]`.

Also, you don't need to copy your coordinates in new variables to use them, you can directly select what you want using your `DS` coordinates. I would suggest 2 ways to do it, using `loc` or `where`:

```
DS_subset = DS.loc[{"lat":slice(lat_bnds[0], lat_bnds[1]), "lon": slice(lon_bnds[0], lon_bnds[1])}].copy()
```

or

```
DS_subset = DS.where((DS.lat > lat_bnds[0]) & (DS.lat < lat_bnds[1]) & (DS.lon > lon_bnds[0]) & (DS.lon < lon_bnds[1]), drop = True)
```